# Get property ToString with formatting

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke

Using reflection I can do `ToString` on a property. But is there a way to supply a formatting while doing this?

```
public static object GetCustomValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetMethod(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

Calling the function like this works fine

```
GetCustomValue(obj, "ToString")
```

But I would like to call it with

```
GetCustomValue(obj, "ToString(\"MMM\")")
```

Is it possible to add formatting to the ToString when calling the `GetMethod` in my function?

Comment: what happens when you use GetPropertyValue(obj, "ToString").ToString("MMM");

Comment: @Anand - I think this means putting logic outside the function, and I would like to keep all logic within the `GetCustomValue` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ToString accepts paramters (the default one doesn't) add an extra optional parameter:

```
public static Object GetCustomValue (object Target, string MethodName, String Format = null)
{
    // Gets the ToString method that accepts a string as the parameter and invoke it.
    return Target.GetType ()
        .GetMethod (MethodName, new [] {typeof (String)})
        .Invoke (Target, new Object[] {Format});
}
```

This way you can call it:

```
GetCustomValue (obj, "ToString", "MMM");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use out of the method name .ToString(format);

```
GetPropertyValue(obj, "ToString").ToString(format);
```